# error in java This element has no attached source and the Javadoc could not be found in the attached Javadoc

Tags: java, android

I saw in one of my android  project, at the beginning of the file:i have used 
import com.sun.media.sound.Toolkit;

When I hover the mouse on the line **"Toolkit   toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();"** in my code to get more details on this, it shows "**This element has no attached source and the Javadoc could not be found in the attached Javadoc.**" i have even included JRE System Library[JRE6] in my android project...

How to resolve this? Any detailed answer will be appreciated.

Comment: This is not an error. Eclipse needs JavaDocs to show the help when you hover the mouse over the code. In your case, it doesn't finds (docs may not be installed on your computer) the JavaDocs for the API element you hovered the mouse on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add java doc and source not the lib in your IDE.

Comment: how to add java doc..i found some java doc http://kickjava.com/284.html how to add this....

Comment: hi thanks a lot...but there has been said that "Download the javadoc of the jar and save it in your local file"..downloding the javadoc in the sense just copying this page content http://kickjava.com/284.htm and pasting it in local file or should i download tell me plz...

Comment: you need to download javadoc not just copy & paste , from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-jsp-135444.html)

Comment: what should i download there, entire javadoc...? i am not getting exactly...and in this link also http://www.vogella.de/articles/Eclipse/article.html#classpath_jarjavadoc they just mention till "Maintain the location to the api".can you tell me in detail..

Comment: what is your exact question ? what you didn;t get ?

Comment: should i download the full javadoc and replace my existing javadoc doc with that..

Comment: *YES*, If you are sure that your existing javadoc is not proper

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137483.html#findjavadoc

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the Open JDK source.  For Java 6, you can find it on the following page:

http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk6/

Download the OpenJDK 6 source bundle and extract the contents.  Once you do that, you can attach the source file through Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, too, I had to go to the 
Project > Properties > Java Build Path
and on the libraries page find the library:

```
> database.jar
```

and expand its arrow:

```
V database
.. Source attachment: (None)
```

click on the Source attachment row, hit edit
then browse to find the path to the frigging database-source.jar
which is right frigging next to it and apply it.

How incredibly lame!