# New computer, broken Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, javadoc

I received my new computer friday and after moving over all of my development projects, my Eclipse "hover" popups have quit working. What I mean is usually when I hover over an element/method/etc... , a small window with the javadoc info will pop up telling me parameters, and a description of the method. Now it just says:

Note: The Javadoc for this element could neither be found in the attached source nor the attached Javadoc.

I've already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516063/error-in-java-this-element-has-no-attached-source-and-the-javadoc-could-not-be-fo) SO post and tried it. Although I will say there are 15 different packages when you go into preferences>java>installed jre's>edit. All point to an http:// address for the docs.

Also the Android documentation I installed doesn't pull up either (which is what I'm developing for).

Comment: Which version of Eclipse?  Last time I checked, Google was warning against using Eclipse 3.6 due to issues with it and the Android SDK.

Comment: Version: Helios Service Release 1

Comment: @R. Bemrose: the tools have been updated for Eclipse 3.6 since Gingerbread's SDK release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this with your standard Java classes/methods/etc. or for custom/Android code? I think your problem is because of your installed JRE. You need to download the Java SE 6 SDK from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html). The JDK has all of the standard Java classes' source files. Once you have it installed, in Eclipse, go to

1. 'Window'->'Preferences'->'Java'->'Installed JREs'.
2. Click the 'Add...' button and select 'Standard VM'.
3. In the 'JRE home' field put "C:\your\path\to\java\jdk1.6_xYourVersionx". It will automatically populate the 'JRE name' field and import all of the necessary jars.
4. Click 'Finish' and then 'OK'.

If it's a problem with some nonstandard Java code, make sure that you've downloaded the source code. Then,

1. Right-click on your project and go to 'Build Path'->'Configure Build Path...'.
2. Select the 'Libraries' tab and expand the entry for your jar file. There should be a sub-entry 'Source attachment: (None)'.
3. Select it and click the 'Edit...' button and put in your path to the source code.
4. Click 'OK' and 'OK'.

NOTE: If you've already installed the JDK, you can edit your current JRE to point to the jdk folder instead of the jre folder i.e. "C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_xx" instead of "C:\Java\jre6".

2nd NOTE: Your bit version of Java must match your bit version of Eclipse, so 32-bit Eclipse requires a 32-bit Java, etc.

Comment: Thank you! I tried changing my folder to JDK instead of JRE, but no go. In the end I believe it was a 64/32 bit mixture issue. I downloaded all 32 bit and it works fine now.

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help. I've run into so many Eclipse problems that I could write a book!